# Geofire does not show location after a certain distance

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

i am using Geofire of firebase on the iOS I am getting getting loading data from my firebase DB but if the location is a bit far it doesnt show in the map as an MKAnnotation....

I need a way to filter in what radius it should search..
i had a look at geo `queryAtRegion:` but it is not the one which should be used..

The code is

```
  [[FIRAuth auth] addAuthStateDidChangeListener:^(FIRAuth * _Nonnull auth, FIRUser * _Nullable user) {

[self.geo setLocation:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: lat longitude:log] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", user.displayName] withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {

       if (error){
         NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);


 } else {

             }

         }];
      }];
```

And for fetching is this..

```
- (void)loadData{
    self.regionQuery = [self.geo queryWithRegion:region];

    NSDate *methodStart = [NSDate date];

    [_regionQuery observeEventType:GFEventTypeKeyEntered withBlock:^(NSString *key, CLLocation *location) {
        pinAnnotation = [[Pin alloc] init];
        [pinAnnotation setKey: key];
        [pinAnnotation setCoordinate:location.coordinate];


        [pinAnnotation setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.latitude]];
        [pinAnnotation setSubtitle:keyy];


        [self.mapView addAnnotation:pinAnnotation];
        self.annotations[key] = pinAnnotation;

        NSDate *methodFinish = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval executionTime = [methodFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:methodStart];
        NSLog(@"executionTime = %f", executionTime);
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter by radius try using geofire's circle query. Check out the readme for an example on the geofire github page [here](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc).